# Connection to ldap with more DC (rotation on/off) (Confluence running on tomcat behind IIS)

Tags: iis, active-directory, tomcat6, confluence

I'm looking here for some advice or refer to some more information how solve this:
I have a Confluence 3.5 which is running on Tomcat6 which is connected by AJP with http server IIS .
In Confluence is possible in Administration to configure connection to an Active Directory through ldap server but i have a problem that nslookup will show me more DC (about 10 IP addresses from which are 6 allways online and 4 offline - they are rotate). How and where (i think that is not possible to configure it directly in confluence so should i configure it in Tomcat servre.xml by "realm" or?) i have to configure it?

thank you in advance for answering my question.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this problem is really very casual but for the case if you will have a troubles with this try [ldap local balancer](http://siag.nu/pen/) . This tool is quering defined AD connection and in my case confluence queries is redirected through "pen" to free and available AD server .
(it create local service on defined port. So confluence i configured to connect to it like on LDAP and its redirect all queries to AD servers)